# How to prevent Webpack generating images in my output folder?

Tags: webpack, urlloader, webpack-file-loader

When I start `webpack`, it compiles my `scss` files and convert small files to `base64`. However, it also copies large images from my `/img` folder into the output folder. How can I prevent `webpack` doing this? I want that `webpack` left references to my original images in the image folder and not copy them into the output folder.

`webpack` creates files that looks like this (in the output folder):

```
5474fbe2d9c2987bc9345fb6cf66fd25.png
```

Here is my webpack config file:

```
module.exports = {
context: path.join(__dirname, "/www"),
entry: [
    "./src/base/style.scss",
],
output: {
    filename: "bundle.css",
    path: path.join(__dirname, "/www/dist")
},
devtool: "source-map",
resolve: {
    extensions: ["", ".scss"]
},
module: {
    loaders: [
        {
            test: /\.(scss|sass)$/,
            loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader', 'postcss-loader', 'raw-loader'),
            exclude: /node_modules/
        },
        {
            test: /\.(png|jpeg|jpg|gif|...)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
            loader: 'url-loader?limit=2000'
        }
    ],
    preLoaders: [
        { test: /\.(scss)$/, loader: "source-map-loader" }
    ]
},
postcss: function () {
    return [autoprefixer, precss];
},
sassLoader: {
    includePaths: [path.join(__dirname, 'www/src')]
},
plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
    new ExtractTextPlugin('bundle.css')
]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

set limit to 1 and set name

```
{
    test: /\.(png|jpeg|jpg|gif|...)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
    loader: 'url-loader',
    query: {
      limit: 1, 
      name: 'img/[name].[ext]?[hash:5]', 
    }
}
```